# How to filter n days from a specific day in SOQL?

Tags: apex, soql

I need to write a soql which is filtering last n ndays from a specific day. Is that possible to write a soql query something like below?

```
SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate <= (2017-12-08T00:00:00Z - LAST_N_DAYS:30)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use could bind variables to assign date dynamically into SOQL query, also calculate the dates as follows:

```
Date dt = System.today();
Date dt2 = dt.addDays(-30); //starting nth day from today

List <Account> lst = [SELECT Name FROM Account 
                      WHERE (CreatedDate <= :dt 
                      AND CreatedDate>=:dt2)];
```